AV ans AR Capture Session Switch
I would like to start both AV and AR session in my app at a time But I can't extract depth map from both at same time, So I started AV session  first and stoped it followed by AR session now I facing the time delay issue between this switch around 150ms,Is it possible to reduce the time delay between this session?
I need to get depth data from both streams without any delay and Atleast I need it in a Sync.
